# Mysql find_in_set slash( / ) separator

Tags: mysql

I have a value of:
 1/2
 3/4/5
 2/3/6

I want to find the value 2 so the result must be
1/2
2/3/6

I dont want to use LIKE operator.
Is there any way to set the separator in FIND_IN_SET function?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `like` or `find_in_set()`.  Here is one method:

```
where find_in_set(2, replace(col, '/', ',')) > 0
```

Comment: thanks..just a novice, I dont know the function replace